# How to get duration between two times in vb .NET

Tags: vb.net

I have two times that I want to get the duration between them.
For example, `00:00:05,967 --> 00:00:08,285` that duration becomes `2.318`
Thank you all for helping me.

Comment: [TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=net-5.0)

Comment: @MaciejLos Thank you for help, dear maciejLos, but can you show me that with cod? Because I am new to coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan)

```
Dim t1 As New TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 5, 967)
Dim t2 As New TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 8, 285)
Console.WriteLine(t2 - t1)
```

Comment: Thank you  a thousand times, it works like a charm